# How do I combine Sprite-Kit and Gameplay-Kit for pathfinding?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I have been using `Sprite-Kit` to create a tile board for a game. The tiles are made up of `SKShapeNodes`. There is one player character and one enemy on the board, placed on different tiles (nodes).

Now, I'm trying to use `Gameplay-Kit` `framework` to implement `pathfinding` between the player character and the enemy, but it doesn't seem like the `Sprite-Kit` `nodes` and the `Gameplay-Kit` `pathfinding` were meant to work together.

The first thing in `pathfinding` is to create a graph. As I envision it, this graph should be made up by the `SKShapeNodes` I have in my `gameBoardArray[x][y]`. The graph, however, looks like something like this, and doesn't seem to take my `[[SKShapeNode]]` as an argument:

```
let graph = GKGridGraph(fromGridStartingAt: int2(0, 0), width: Int32(Maze.dimensions), height: Int32(Maze.dimensions), diagonalsAllowed: false)
```

This is just a default graph from another project. The thing is that I don't quite understand it and don't understand how I should connect this to my `gameBoardArray[x][y]`.

Or am I completely missing how the graph is supposed to work? Isn't it supposed to be based on the gameBoard I have already created?

EDIT
I have tried the following:

```
let startNode = GKGraphNode2D(point: float2(x: Float(iBeginning), y: Float(jBeginning)))

let endNode = GKGraphNode2D(point: float2(x: Float(iEnd), y: Float(jEnd)))

let graph = GKGraph()

let pathNodes = graph.findPath(from: startNode, to: endNode) as! [GKGraphNode2D]
```

The `startNode` and `endNode` use the correct values from the player and the enemy positions. Then I use `graph.findPath`... But then what? I don't think I understand how to actually use it. For example, is there a way I can mark the pathway with colors so that I can see if it even works? Or what am I supposed to do with it. (Note: I checked the documentation).

Comment: a graph does not need to know what a shape node is.... a shape node is something visual.  See the apple docs to understand how to use path finding. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Pathfinder_GameplayKit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016461

Comment: @KnightOfDragon Thanks, I have tried a bit more, but I'm not sure if it works or how I can check if it works. Please see edit above :)

Comment: Your graph is empty.....  you need to populate it before you can find a path

Comment: Yes, but that's the problem, as it doesn't take my [[SKShapeNode]]

Comment: Because skshapenode is graphics.  You are trying to fill up your gas powered car with maple syrup here lol.  Look at the example I sent you.